# Condition comparing string against bool returning undesired result unless strict comparison is used

Tags: php, string, comparison, conditional-statements

In PHP 5.3, i stumbled upon this case:

```
$test=true;
return $test=='alternate';
```

It returns true. I do not understand why.

Why does it return true?

Additionally it is to say that:

```
$test=true;
return $test==='alternate';
```

Returns false. Rightfully so. I am aware that it is better to use strict comparison in most cases, but i would like to understand what happens in the first case?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Non-empty strings are considered to be true. Loosely comparing true with true yields true.

See http://www.php.net/manual/en/types.comparisons.php for details. And always use strict comparisons. You rarely ever need loose ones, but in every case you induce the doubt whether you meant to type-cast the variables or if it is an error.